# What's the CoreText equivalent to AppKit's NSObliquenessAttributeName?

Tags: ios, cocoa, drawing, core-text, italic

I'm drawing some text in Mac/iOS cross-platform code using CoreText. I may be using fonts that do not have a real "Italic" version installed in the OS for all users, but they need to be aware that the text is italic even then.

With AppKit's NSAttributedString -drawAtPoint:, I can use NSObliquenessAttributeName to make the text slanted (and thus look italic -- well, oblique). CoreText doesn't seem to have an equivalent for this attribute. At least I found none in CTStringAttributes.h (not that there's any documentation even years after CoreText was released).

Does anyone know how I can get oblique text with CoreText on iOS?

Comment: Documentation for Core Text? You mean this? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CoreText_Framework_Ref/

Comment: I clicked "Reference" in Mac dev center, typed CoreText into the search field, and all I got was three sample apps. How'd you pull out these secret docs?

Comment: It's the top Reference hit on https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/search/?q=core+text .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Displaying a font that has no italic trait as italic is generally a bad idea. However, I can understand that there are some cases where this has to be enforced anyways.

The only solution that comes to my mind right now is to create a custom font with a sheared font matrix:

```
CGAffineTransform matrix = CGAffineTransformMake(1, tan(degreesToRadians(0)), tan(degreesToRadians(20)), 1, 0, 0);  
CTFontRef myfont = CTFontCreateWithName(CFSTR("Helvetica"), 48, &matrix);
```

You'll have to play with the matrix and see what brings the best results. *(Please not that this is a fake code mix out of my head and the internet.)*

Comment: I think you want a shear matrix rather than a rotation matrix.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that, with Alastair's correction. I'd be happy not to have to display faux italics, but it's pre-existing data that used to do this, and I can't just drop information that used to display just fine previously. :-)

Comment: Yes, a slant matrix is what you'd want.

Comment: Another workaround would be to fall back to a different font that does have italics. But that would probably look even worse...

Comment: Looking at this again, I note that Max’s matrix actually *is* a shear matrix (and not a rotation matrix as he originally said).

Comment: I've fixed the text. now it's sheared :)

Answer (score 9):

I’d try using the affine transform argument to `CTFontCreateWithName()` with a shear matrix. For instance

```
CGAffineTransform matrix = { 1, 0, 0.5, 1, 0, 0 };
CTFontRef myFont = CTFontCreateWithName(CFSTR("Helvetica"), 48, &matrix);
```

That will create quite an extreme skew (assuming I got it right), but you get the idea.

**Update:**

In fact, [the documentation appears to imply that this is the right way to do things](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFontRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005110-CH3-SW40).

Comment: Good answer but please never make me have to look at this.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried, but according to [*iOS Programming Pushing The Limits*](http://books.google.de/books?id=mGflUpKh1dQC&pg=PA339&lpg=PA339&dq=coretext+oblique&source=bl&ots=C2naHe3DGt&sig=GzNhFsvnTMLlfj326Piupcw1-Z4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kA5NT5NkyN6yBtLv-JgP&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=coretext%20oblique&f=false), passing `kCTFontItalicTrait` to `CTFontCreateCopyWithSymbolicTraits` will choose true italic if available, and oblique otherwise. There's also [`kCTFontSlantTrait`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Carbon/Reference/CTFontDescriptorRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/kCTFontSlantTrait) for manual decimal slant up to 30 degrees.

Comment: As far as I know this only works for fonts that actually feature a italic variant. I understood the question as if the OP wanted to display italic with a font that does not have italic.

Comment: I tried kCTFontSlantTrait, that didn't help (I get the feeling that's a read-only attribute). The italic trait picks an oblique font in cases like Courier, that actually come with a pre-built oblique variant, but some of the fonts I need to display don't even have that.